# Animate subviews

Tags: ios, swift

My question is really easy. I just can't figure it out how to animate between subviews.

Here's how I'm animating between VC's.

**I'm using Hero transitions for Swift**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            let main = segue.destination as! ViewController
            main.hero.modalAnimationType = .selectBy(presenting: .zoomSlide(direction: .left), dismissing: .zoomSlide(direction: .right
                ))
}
```

This is how I'm presenting subview

```
self.view.addSubview(featureView!)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear (what do you mean by "animate between subviews"?), please see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate for info on how to animate your featureView.  For example to have featureView fade in you'd start with alpha=0 and animate the alpha to 1.0

Comment: you can animate View: `UIView.animate(withDuration:)` or animate `CALayers` using `CABasicAnimation ` before adding them to your view as sublayers: `view.layer.addsublayer`

Comment: What kind of animation are you trying to give your transition? Are you planning to push the new view onto the old view? Are you trying to just create a fade-in effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the view transition functions like `transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)` or `transition(from:to:duration:options:completion:)`. The one with an `animations` parameter takes a closure that actually performs the transition animation.

The second one that does not take an animations parameter is simpler, and does the transition for you using options flags that you specify.